# Oracle Range partition based on Unix Epoch Timestamp

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Is it possible for us to range partition a table which has unique column as timestamp stored in oracle in `Unix Epoch format` .

There are lot of options we have w.r.t to oracle partition but I want to know how can we partition a table which has Unix Epoch timestamp stored at database level.

As this column is referenced in the front-end, we want to do range partition on this column only.

This is how the table structure looks like .

```
Timestamp      number 
Reference id   number
Value          integer
```

The table is going to store one year worth of critical data and the timestamp column stores the exact unix epoch timestamp . We would be  interested to partition the table into 12 partitions based on timestamp values for each month .

This is how the unix timestamp we are converting to date format using below sql.

```
select (TO_DATE('1970-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD') + unix_timestamp / 86400000) from dbname;
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that Oracle stores internally time values same way - number of seconds (fractional parts of seconds) since midnight. And precision is up to nanoseconds - timestamp(9). Anyway it does not matter how it is stored internally. I would recommend to use standard TIMESTAMP datatype. And yes, it is possible to build partitions on TIMESTAMP column